# How can I modify keyboard shortcuts for Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-snow-leopard, firefox-3.6

I recently started using Firefox as my primary web browser, and I would like to change some of the default keyboard shortcuts, especially the ones used to switch between tabs. Can this be done?

I took a peek through the Firefox directory in "Application Support", as well as the application bundle itself, but nothing jumped out. Google searches have also proved fruitless.

***Update:*** I'm running Firefox version 3.6 for Mac OSX 10.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [keyconfig](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1537) extension for that?

At this [link](http://pqrs.org/firefox/extensions/functions_for_keyconfig/) some people say they got it to work on Firefox 3:

> @ M.C yes it is !!! (compatible with
>   Firefox 3.6) you have to extract the file
>   "install.rdf" from
>   "functions_for_keyconfig-1.4.0.xpi"
>   with a deziper prog like "WinZip" in
>   Windows or "file roller" in Linux.
>
> Edit
>   "install.rdf" and search for this line:
>   "3.5.*".
>   Then replace with
>   "3.6.*".
>
> In "functions_for_keyconfig-1.4.0.xpi"
>   replace file "install.rdf" with
>   the modified one. Save. Open your Firefox 3.6,
>   drag and drop the file
>   "functions_for_keyconfig-1.4.0.xpi" in
>   Firefox windows. That's it.

Comment: Key examples: http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig/examples.html

Comment: For anyone else who goes down this path: Once you've installed the add-on, it places a new menu item called "Keyconfig" in the "Tools" menu. The menu item brings up a window which can be used to assign snippets of JavaScript to individual keystrokes. My previous link goes to some example snippets.